# How to change kendo grid column width after bound in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, width

I'm trying to set width for one of the columns kendo grid.
Here the simple code:

```
                @(Html.Kendo()
                  .Grid<MyObject>()
                  .Name("Name")
                  .TableHtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: auto;" })
                  .Columns(c => {
                      c.Bound(m => m.ObjectId).Hidden();
                      c.Bound(m => m.Type).Title()
                      //Bound other fields
                          if (Model.Property)
                          {
                              c.Bound(m => m.Price).Title()
                              .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new {title = "Price"});
                              //Here I want to change the width of my first column
                              c.Container.Columns.Where(x => x.Title == "Type").FirstOrDefault.Width(200);
                          }
                  })
                  .Scrollable(src => src.Height(261))
                  .DataSource(ds => ds
                      .Ajax()
                      .Events(e => e.Error("app.ui.kendo.onGridError").RequestEnd("app.ui.project.onRequestEnd"))
                      .Read(r => r
                          .Action("Action", "Controller", new { Id = @Model.Id })
                          .Type(HttpVerbs.Get))))
```

The problem is that compiler said "Method, delegate or event expected". Are there another ways to change width after bounding the column?

Comment: why you don't change it directly on c.Bound(m=>m.Type).Title().Width(200) ?

Comment: @user5135401 Because I need to change inside the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

To Change it after bound you have to

1) Attach an event in kendo grid like

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeModel>()
.Name(Model)
.Events(e => e.DataBound("some_name"))
```

2) In Jquery

```
 function some_name(e) {
 // Access the column here to set the width
$('#SomeField').width(percentage)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `$('#Price').width(value)` in my case?
If so it wasn't changed.

Comment: Mistake in my comment. I'm trying $('#Type').width(200) and nothing happened.

Comment: check the id of the html that is rendered , I dont think you ll be rendering with #type

Comment: I have an Id of grid and fields in it. I need to access to the field but they don't have an id.

Comment: Yes you need to have a selector if you want to modify after the columns are bound

Comment: You should try something similar to this
columns.Bound(p => p.Enabled).ClientTemplate(
    "<input type='checkbox' value='#= ProductID #' " +
        "# if (Enabled) { #" +
            "checked='checked'" +
        "# } #" +
    "/>"
);

Comment: I just need to change column width.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered before by Telerik themselves. Here ya go!
http://www.telerik.com/forums/change-column-widths-after-grid-created

It looks like it's unsupported out of the box, or was so in 2013 at least. Personally I would just grab the options from the grid, change the width of the column you need, and then re-apply these options to the grid.

My workplace uses Kendo for all our UI's and this is probably the easiest way I've found to edit multiple options after databound, even if they're not exposed through Kendo methods.

*Code below is just an example, probably missed something but should get you started.*

```
var grid = $("#Name").data("kendoGrid");
var opts = grid.options;
opts.columns[0].width = "1000px";
grid.setOptions(y);
```

I don't believe this requires a grid refresh, but it might. Also I believe you can use the string name of the field tied to the column instead of the index.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. Right now I've found this working way:
`$("#grid .k-grid-header-wrap").find("colgroup col").width(width);
$("#grid .k-grid-content").find("colgroup col").width(width);` but I can't find the field by this way..

Comment: Also it refresh the grid.